# How to send an email from an HTML5 form

Tags: php, html, email, forms, http-post

I am having issues trying to submit a form and have it email the data submitted. I understand this is usually done but I seem to be having problems figuring out what's wrong here. So the current code is.

```
 <div class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
            <p class="a">Free Estimates</p>
            <div class="form">
                 <div class="form-text">
                 <form action="../contact.php">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your Name*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your E-mail*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}">
                    <input name="PNumber" type="text" class="Subject" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Website';}">
                </div>
                     <textarea placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
                     <div class="clear"> </div>
                     <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">                  
             </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

I have a file called mailfrom.php but I think this is where I'm having problems

```
<?php
$to      = 'contact@qixty.com';
$subject = 'New Request from Website';
$message = $_POST['mytextarea'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@qixty.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: contact@qixty.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

After I hit submit on the main page, I am brought to a new blank page.

Changes the URL from `http://qixty.com`
to
`http://qixty.com/mailfrom.php?PNumber=Phone+Number`

Any help would be great. 
I know I could just insert a link to mailto like this

```
<a href="mailto:contact@qixty.com?cc=faulkerson@gmail.com" class="btn" data-type="submit">Send</a>
```

But that doesn't post the form data. I would like to have it send an email to me with the form data in the body of the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- Add `method="POST"` to the `<form>`
- Add `name` attributes (which match the keys you are trying to use in `$_POST`) to your form controls (e.g. `<textarea name="mytextarea"></textarea>`).

If you don't want a blank page to be displayed to the browser, then output some content from the PHP script as well as just calling `mail()`.

You should also stop abusing the `value` attribute as a `<label>`. Use a proper `<label>` element and leave the `value` attribute for providing a default value.

Comment: Thanks everyone Quentin This worked for me. I just got an email. I can figure out my other issues now :) This question has been answered.

Comment: Quentin send me your BTC address and ill send ya some bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

if your action file name is `mailform.php` then this

```
<form action="../contact.php">
```

should be

```
<form action="../mailform.php">
```

if both files are in same directory then remove `../` from action attribute.

## UPDATE

---

form

---

```
<div class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
            <p class="a">Free Estimates</p>
            <div class="form">
                 <div class="form-text">
                 <form method='post' action="../mailform.php">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your Name*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your E-mail*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}">
                    <input name="PNumber" type="text" class="Subject" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Website';}">
                </div>
                     <textarea name='mytextarea' placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
                     <div class="clear"> </div>
                     <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">                  
             </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

---

mailform.php

---

```
$to      = 'contact@qixty.com';
$subject = 'New Request from Website';
$message = $_POST['mytextarea'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@qixty.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: contact@qixty.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// this will help you to get the status mail sent or not
if($send) :
   echo "Email sent";
else :
    echo "Email sending failed";
endif;
```

Comment: My apologies I was trying a few things and forgot to change that back.   <form action="../mailform.php"> is what i have currently on the form html and I have that file located one directory up so thats right i believe. thanks for pointing that out. I should have proofread before i submitted the question

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered. I had html issues php was fine.

```
<div class="form">
                 <div class="form-text">
                 <form action="../mailfrom.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your Name*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                    <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your E-mail*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}">
                    <input name="PNumber" type="text" class="Subject" value="Phone Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Website';}">
                </div>
                     <textarea name="mytextarea" placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
                     <div class="clear"> </div>
                     <input type="submit" Label="SEND MESSAGE">                  
             </div>
```